# Switch to a Visual Design from another Visual Design

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I'm working in java me. I created two visual designs, First.java and Second.java both of which contains form displayables.

I added an Ok command to a form in First.Java and the user is expected to switch to SecondForm in Second.java but I get this error `non-static method getSecondForm() cannot be referenced from a static context`.

How can I fix this?

Both files are in the same package. Here's the source code

```
 public void commandAction (Command command, Displayable displayable) {

    if (displayable == firstForm) {

        if (command == exitCommand) {
            exitMIDlet();

        } else if (command == okCommand) {

            switchDisplayable(null, Second.getSecondForm());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: show the snippet of the code you are having problems with. Without this, it is quite hard to find out what went wrong

Comment: I just did. I was trying to post it and the system was reporting some code format errors

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to change declaration of the method `getSecondForm` in Second.java to make it static.

If it currently looks like

```
Displayable getSecondForm() //... whatever code is there
```

then after change it should look like

```
static Displayable getSecondForm() //... whatever code is there
```

Note above change will fix the `non-static method getSecondForm...` error you mentioned but there is a chance that it will cause new compilation errors in file `Second.java`. You will need to fix these new errors, most likely by adding couple `static` keywords here and there, similar to how it is shown above.

---

<sub>Note this is [java](/questions/tagged/java) language basic stuff; if you get stuck fixing this, consider taking a break to study some tutorial for beginners.</sub>

Comment: I appreciate. I'll try that and see how it goes. Thanks again