# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java-me, lcdui

I'm working with java me. I tried to switch to a displayable(form2) in Second.java from an okCommand in another displayble(form1) in First.java (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14068709/839601) on that).

I got an error `non-static method getForm2() cannot be referenced from a static context`. I had to add the word static to form2 declaration and also at the getForm2 method in Second.java before it could work.

Problem now is that a backCommand in form2 can't switch back to form1 in First.java and it pops up the error `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`.

I paused and took some time to refresh myself on the language fundamentals on how the static keyword is used and I got to know that a static method is a class method and a non-static method is an instance method and that a non-static cannot call a static method unless an instance of the non-static method is created and also that a static method can't call a non-static method.

I'm really not understanding the implementation as I should, and I'd appreciate some clarification using my example above.

Here's the source below from Second.java the error is coming from `form2.setCommandListener(this);`

```
 public static Form getForm2() {

    if (form2 == null) {                                 

        form2 = new Form("form");                                    
        form2.addCommand(getBackCommand());

        form2.setCommandListener(this);                                  
    }                         

    return form2;
```

Comment: If you are getting this error - "non-static method getForm2() cannot be referenced from a static context" - can you paste in the code that is actually trying to call "getForm2"?

Comment: Here's the code. But I fixed this by adding the static keyword in the declaration and getForm2 method in Second.java

    public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
        if (displayable == form1) {
            if (command == exitCommand) {
                exitMIDlet();
            } else if (command == okCommand) {
                switchDisplayable(null, Second.getForm2());
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

You have a `static` method, but are using `this`. But `this` doesn't exist. It would normally reference to an *instance* of the class, but you don't have one here.

If your method wasn't `static` and you instantiated an instance of this class then this would work.

e.g.

```
Second s = new Second();
Form f = s.getForm2(); // if this method wasn't static
```

Making that method static means little more than namespacing. There isn't an associated instance and no `this`.

Comment: Pls break this down further so I can really get you pls

Answer (score 2):

There are couple options. First is to create a static instance of `Second` and use it in the `getForm2`:

```
 //...
 // static instance
 private static Second instance = new Second(/* put constructor arguments here, if any */);
 //...
 public static Form getForm2() {

    if (form2 == null) {                                 

        form2 = new Form("form");                                    
        form2.addCommand(getBackCommand());

        form2.setCommandListener(instance); // --> replace "this" with "instance"
    }
    //...
```

---

From the issues you describe though, I would prefer another option - returning to design you had in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14068709/839601) and use an instance of `Second` as an argument passed via constructor of `First`.

Your First.java would then have lines like:

```
 //...
 private final Second second; // instance needed for commandAction
 //...
 First(Second second) { // constructor with parameter
    this.second = second; // save the parameter
    //...
 }
```

Then, `commandAction` method in First.java could use code like:

```
switchDisplayable(null, second.getSecondForm());
// instead of Second.getSecondForm()
```

Comment: First option didn't work. It says Constructor Second cannot be applied to given types. Found no arguments.

The Second option didn't work either. It says "variable second might not have been initialized" and on the commandAction,  it says "cannot find variable instance"

Comment: From my previous question. I had done as instructed and can switch to form2 in Second.java. What I'm trying to do now is add a backCommand in form2 that takes the user back to form1 in First.java

Comment: @KenWaribo for first option to work, you need pass the right parameters to constructor of `Second` (it is not shown in your snippet). As for second option, there was a typo in my code sorry - corrected

Comment: Using the second option, on the line that has the First.java constructor public First(){} I still get the error "variable second might not have been initialized

Comment: @KenWaribo you need to take a closer look at constructors of `First` class; parameter `Second second` is intended to be set/used in every one of these; from what you wrote it looks like you need to remove `public First(){}` - and, of course fix the compliation errors that appear after that

Comment: The First class has only one constructor. The one I posted above. I tried passing in params and it blown multiple errors but when I commented it out, I get a runtime IllegalAccessException. Pls do u mind if I 4ward the project to u, it's a very basic application I'm trying to use to gain experience for a project I'd lyk to do later. It's a Netbeans project but can be exported to The Nokia IDE for Java ME(Eclipse) v1

Comment: This is what I did now after much trial and error. I added this line in First.java     
Second s = new Second(this);

then in my command action, I did:
switchDisplayable(null, s.getSecondForm());

and once more it worked, I could once again select the Ok command and be taken to secondForm in Second.java. This time I didn't make the secondForm static as initially adviced.

Comment: But when I tried adding a backCommand which is supposed to take me back to firstForm in First.java I get ds error again 'non-static method getFirstForm() cannot be referenced from a static context', so I tried creating a reference in Second.java same way I did in First.java

here's the code:

    First f = new First();

then in command action I did ds on the backCommand:

   switchDisplayable(null, f.getForm());
   
This time, it compiled without errors. But at runtime I get a SecurityException MIDlet Manager ERROR: Illegal attempt to construct hello.First@e938beb1

Comment: glad to hear that it worked. As for your next issue, it looks deserving its **[own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not qute welcome")**, consider posting it separately

Comment: Hahaha...what's that on that link? Is that how you ppl see us. Every expert was once a newbie in programming you know?

Comment: @KenWaribo nope, it's rather matters of UI difference - it's how SE oldtimers see those more familiar with traditional programming forums. Being familiar with both kinds I can assure you that what here is felt like "chameleon" would be perfectly acceptable in traditional forum discussion, and in forum everyone would do that way, no matter experts or newbies. It just takes a while to get used to the way how Q&A is structured here